# AlarmManager not working after sometime in some Chinese phones

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I am using an IntentService in my app which is to be triggered everyday at a specific time.For this, I am using Alarm Manager to trigger my service. In most of the phones (like Samsung,Sony,etc) this is working perfect.But in Chinese brands like Vivo, Xiaomi, etc the Alarm Manager works for sometime but doesn't works for a period of 24 hours. So, I had to manually suggest to my users to allow app autostart from their app permissions(it is also quite uncomfortable for vivo users due to their different android versions).

I used RTC_WAKEUp, but that also doesn't seems to work for chinese handsets

I want to make my app flawless working without the need of user(to allow permissions). How can I acheive this? wishes some help from you.Thanks

```
  Intent intent=new Intent(this,MyAlarmService.class);
    PendingIntent myPendingIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,intent,0);
   myAlarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,timeInMillis,AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,myPendingIntent);
```

Comment: Did you get any solution? Please share the solution if you resolved it at your end.